# Console apps like cmd edit

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is it possible to create console apps like the Edit app in CMD with visual basic or C#? I want the program to respond to mouse input, have menubar, mssgboxes and windows.

Comment: Unless your Edit clone can handle extremley large files like the original Edit can, don't bother. I wish Edit worked on x64 systems!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible!  Instead of doing it completely from scratch, check out [Curses Sharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/).  It is a wrapper for the curses library, which helps in building applications like this.

I must admit though, I have never used it.  Please let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Console API provided with .NET is not suitable for that sort of development. You'll need to do lots of P/Invoke to the platform console API. I would really suggest WinForms/WPF if you need GUI.

If you really want to do it anyway, you'll need to implement low level mouse/keyboard hooks. This will get you started: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx

Answer (score -2):

If you want it to run on DOS, you can't (because C#/vb.net don't run on DOS). If you want it to run on Windows, I think you're better off using Windows Forms or WPF.

To answer your question; it is probably possible but it would take an enormous amount of work and for the above reasons I don't think it would have any payoff.

Comment: Why the crap did I get -2 on this?